# How can I share session variables across sites?

Tags: 7, sessions

On my main Drupal site, users need to be able to select a display preference (e.g. 'high visibility'). This will be available to registered and anonymous users but only for their session, so I plan to store their preference in a session variable, for example with `$_SESSION['display'] = $my_preference;`.

Another Drupal site runs on a subdomain of the main site, and needs the same functionality. And if the user visits both sites, it would be great to remember their preference.

I think that if I uncomment this line in both site's settings.php, session variables can be accessed across sites on the same domain?

```
$cookie_domain = 'maindomain.com';
```

So then I could set $_SESSION['display'] on one site, and retrieve $_SESSION['display'] on the other?

Also, one site runs on Drupal 6 and the other on Drupal 7. Will this be a problem? Is caching for anonymous users going to cause problems?

Am I on the right lines, or is this plan flawed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to do this

- Using session

Use a single session table for both the site using settings.php [set up](http://drupal.org/node/291373)

- Using Cookie

Use same cookie domain for both site and set cookie available in all pages.

Comment: ah of course - sessions (and probably users) table needs to be shared between the sites. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Be careful sharing tables across different sites. That particular solution can have erratic side effects.